# MATLAB Stand alone executable

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, executable

I would like to know the easiest way to create a stand alone exe for MATLAB code. I do not have the MATLAB compiler. (Mathworks asks you to buy a license).

MATLAB is the only programming language I know. Step by step instructions (especially for non-MATLAB stuff) would be appreciated.

ver:
MATLAB Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a)
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Version 6.1 (Build 7600)
Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_12-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure the only way to do it is with the MATLAB Compiler.

Comment: That the reason why the MATLAB compiler is so expensive ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I'll just get the compiler...

Answer (score 5):

If it's pure MATLAB code, you can try the method that I proposed on programmers.SE ([here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41644/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-communicate-scientific-engineering-programming-to-c/41650#41650)) :

"You can use the free scilab to C converter.
The procedure would be

- Convert your code from Matlab to
  Scilab with [M2SCI
  tools](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/About_M2SCI_tools.html),
- Convert the Scilab code to C using
  ["Scilab 2
  C"](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/scilab2c/),
- Cross test the codes,
- Use a
  profiler to search bottlenecks that
  need a human eye.

Ideally no knowledge of Scilab is needed in the process and it's easy enough to take some time try this solution (in practice, it's maybe not as simple ...)

Note : I didn't try this but it's a solution I envisage myself for similar reasons."

Otherwise as noted by gnovice, the MATLAB compiler is mandatory.

Comment: I tried scilab... I keep getting the error: !--error 34 
Incorrect control instruction syntax. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you convert the code with the tool ? The syntax is different between Matlab and Scilab. The best is probably to try all the process with a simple code and only after with all your code.

Comment: I am using scilab 5.0. All I did was type 'mfile2sci' in the command prompt, hit enter, a GUI shows up asking you to select your file and directory. I tried it with a simple m- file and it worked. But it gave me an error for my function file. Do you know what the error means?

Comment: I don't. It seems to be a problem with a control instruction (if, for, ...) but if it works well with Matlab, it's strange.